# How do you make a skin tone metallic brown?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, skin-tones

First of, i'd like to say that i'm partially colour blind which makes this task more difficult for me. I'm wondering if it is possible to change a person's skin tone in photoshop from something pretty common to look (in terms of color and contrast) like the image below:

https://500px.com/photo/102402623/felix-by-sergey-fedotov
[image]

Do you think this is done by using some light modifiers and then just a touch of post-processing? Or could i just take some relatively pale skin and do the same just in photoshop?

I've noticed that a similar thing happens when you raise the blacks in curves and then lower some dark colours to create some contrast. It creates a beautiful effect in terms of contrast, but the colour is still off.

Here's another example of a more usual  skin tone:

https://500px.com/photo/105117951/kate-by-anastasia-smanyuk?from=popular&only=People
[image]

Would it be possible to match skin tones in terms of color and contrast in the image 2 to look like the first image?

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions and edit your question accordingly. This is particularly important with external links, because we never know when it will vanish. Having an example is good, but please make your question understandable from the text.

Comment: On your edit — just inlining the image does not really help. Please *describe* the effect you see.

Comment: @mattdm I've stated in the question that i'm looking merely to color correct skin tones to look like the one in the image. That's all there is to it, as i don't think this kind of skin tone is natural and straight out of camera.

Comment: *What does the skin tone in the image look like to you?* Why and in what way do you think it is unnatural?

Comment: @mattdm Like i said .. i'm partially color blind and i simply don't know how to answer it. The colors look somewhat desaturated and "metallic brown" (like i said - i have a problem with colors so it might not really be brown). Usually skin tones are lighter and less contrasty. And maybe there are people with skin tones like that, but i'm sure you can just take any white person and do something in PS to match this look as well. I've added another picture to show the difference.

Comment: @SailorCire like i mentioned in the post, the second image is there as an example of the more standard tones that i would like to "convert" to the first image's look. It's only there as a starting point.

Comment: Possibly covered by [How do you achieve this brownish skin color moody look on your photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57039/how-do-you-achieve-this-brownish-skin-color-moody-look-on-your-photos)

Comment: @mattdm I've read that post before posting mine. I just don't know, my eyes don't quite see them as related. But, obviously, i could be wrong. And examples from dan winters shoots also looked different to me.

Comment: There's another example around here of a similar question about skin toned in a way that seems similar to me, but I can't find it right now. In any case, this goes to illustrate my point: we all see these things differently (and it's not just the color vision deficiency), which is why it really helps to expand in text what you see (even when it feels difficult to put into words).

Comment: I updated this post: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50918/things-to-consider-when-creating-realistic-highlights-and-dark-reflections-on-me/50925#50925 with a technique for the metalic part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the metallic looks mainly comes from the dodge and burn technique.
This video shows the technique well. [How to Dodge & Burn in Photoshop by Elena Jasic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CsyS2Gd9lY).

I tried to achieve the similar effects of the first image you provided.
The left image is before any edits, and right image is after the edits. I hope this is the effects which you are trying to achieve!
[image]

1. Lower the saturation by colors. Especially lower reds and yellows to achieve brown skin tone.

[image]

2. Adjust the curves.

[image]

3. Do the dodge and burn. Done!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort. While it does not look exactly like my first image (doesn't quite have the "metallic gloss") - it's quite an easy technique that could probably be improved upon easy (probably by adding more contrast, saturating a little bit more etc.). Anyway, it's easy enough so i'm accepting this answer :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is very easily done in Post Processing, I'll do it using Photoshop.

I did it with 3 adjustment layers which I'll explain.

First I did a Color Fill with Blend Mode set to fill using a bronze color. I then adjusted the Blend-If Lightness, Underlying Layer to 0/231, 50/255

[image]

Then I did a Contrast Curve on the Lightness pulling the midtones down and flattening the shadows a bit. I also lowered the opacity of this layer.

[image]

Then I lowered the saturation just slightly for the final look

[image]

For the results:

[image]

Because we bumped contrast a bit I would probably then do some dodge and burn on the cheek, pores, forehead and nose. Maybe dial the entire look back by grouping the adjustments and lowering the opacity. I'd probably also mask the shirt and give it its own adjustment to bring it back to a more neutral white.

Answer (score 1):

There are some components to that "look".  In this case I think the make-up and lighting are the more important to get right from the start, particularly because they can't be corrected later.

- Make-up makes the skin appear more uniform in texture as well as colour, and can give a gleam or a flat appearance.  It can also go some way to getting the colour you want.
- Lighting is very important.  Ring flash (or just some flash near camera) was used for the first image, catching gleam in the skin more, while the second image has some softer more traditional (3-point lighting) setup.
- De-saturating the image a little.  Especially in the first photo, the saturation is cut a lot.
- Playing with tone curves (eg in raw developing software, or adding curves layers later in photoshop).  Play around until the skin tones have that nice sheen to them, it's essentially an S-curve, which boosts contrast, with the flattening at the top around where the skin tones are in terms of brightness.

You should be able to achieve all you want with just the above, but you can also add a colour cast, or add a gradient map (but with a blend mode or less than 100% opacity on top of the original).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the question is: *how to constrain skin tones to only brown hues; getting rid of the naturally occurring red patches and bluish tints that some subjects have.*

I've substituted skin tones using a combination of gradient maps and layer masks. For my answer to make sense, you'll need to be familiar with both techniques.

Create a gradient map that consists of the colors that you want in the skin tones, this would be from a very dark to a light brown for example. The gradient map adjustment layer will limit the image to only those brown tones you have specified.

In your example above, the dark skin value is around #2d2115 and the light is about #c0aea2. You can use more than two colors in the gradient if you want.

Now that the whole image is in tones of brown, the next step is to mask out the parts of the image that you don't want affected. Use either a (raster) layer mask that you paint on, or a vector mask that you draw on with the pen tool. (you could use both in combination if you are experienced with that)

Final tweaks would be to adjust the overall opacity of the adjustment layer, or setting it to "color" mode instead of normal in order to preserve some qualities of the original image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually know of this technique. I used to create gradient maps from lots of different colors based on the original image. Unfortunately, the result would in most cases be a "flat" image. Why? Because most images are different in contrast and tonal values. For instance, you can get the tones from image 1 and apply them to image 2 and you'll get a completely different look. What i'm looking for is this metallic contrast as wwll as the colors. I've seen people use lightroom only to turn image 2 into image 1 so i guess there should be some simpler technique for that.

Comment: @Marius if you'll upload one of your own images (one you own copyright to) I will attempt the technique as a demonstration.

Comment: Thank you, but there's no need for a demonstration. I understand what you said in your post and it's a good tip. But for really good results this is quite time consuming, as it requires lots of sampled colors and contrast adjustments. I've already done this in the past myself, but didn't like how long it took. As i'm pretty sure this can be achieved easier with maybe just a camera raw filter's temperature / curves combinations or something similar. Still trying to find a simpler way myself.

Comment: @Marius OK, then. By the way, contrast can be controlled by the gradient adjustment layer without an extra step. I've not found it to take a lot of time to get the effect. I have many pre-set gradient maps that I use for exactly this purpose.

Comment: You're right about that too. Maybe it's just a matter of preference or my color-blindness issue that this technique doesn't work all that well for me. Difficult to say. Thanks for your help!